# Events - Why is context stored two different ways?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am looking through the [source of backbone](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js), the events part, and for the most part it makes sense, except for the line in which context is stored twice.

In one case, it gets the value passed to `on()`.  In the second instance, it gets the value passed, but if none is passed, it get the current context - `this`.

```
on: function(name, callback, context) {
  if (!(eventsApi(this, 'on', name, [callback, context]) && callback)) return this;
  this._events || (this._events = {});
  var list = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);
  list.push({callback: callback, context: context, ctx: context || this}); // here
  return this;
},
```

One thing that is confusing is that sometimes `this._events[name]` is saved to local variable `list` (on and off) and other times it is saved to local variable `effects` (trigger).

**Explicit uses of each**

- `.ctx` is used in `triggerEvents()`.
- `.context` is used in `off()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctx` is used as the value of `this` inside the callback function when an event is triggered.  So for example, inside the `initialize` method of a view you might do this:

```
this.model.on('change', this.render, this); // where 'this' is the view
```

Then inside the render method, when that event is triggered, `this` will be the view.

`context` is used so that certain usages of `off` can work, giving you more ways to selectively remove event callbacks.  For example, if you wanted to remove the callbacks added to the model in the above example, you could do this:

```
this.model.off(null, null, this); // where 'this' is the view from above
```

This would remove any event handlers added to that model where the view was passed as the context.

That line would not remove an event added like:

```
this.model.on('change', this.foo, bar);  // context is bar
```

It could be useful if you hooked up to several events and wanted to remove them all at once, while not removing any callbacks added with different context.  However, now that Events has `listenTo`, it is probably easier to use that instead, since the view could just call `stopListening`.

The reason `context` and `ctx` are stored separately, is because they can be different values.  `context` is always the third value passed to `on` and it could be null or undefined, while `ctx` is either that value, if available, or `this`.

Comment: important to note that, passing the context not only changes the value of `this` in the callback but also the `signature` of the event